# How to scale image X and Y within Android's ImageView equally?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, imageview

I am trying to get a logo to have the same scaling no matter the size of the parent's view. Right now the logo is scaled down vertically but no horizontally causing the logo to have a smushed look to it. I'd like it to scale both x and y equally so that it maintains it's form without a smushed or stretched look.

I have tried various scaleTypes, but they haven't seemed to help thus far.

XML CODE FOR BUTTON:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@android:color/transparent" />
```

FULL XML CODE (GIVE CONTEXT):

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:baselineAligned="false" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="right|bottom"
                android:shadowColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="THE BLIND GOAT"
                android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/help"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:text="HELP"
                android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textSize="9dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="monospace" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/help"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:text="SETTINGS"
                android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textSize="9dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="monospace" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/logout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/settings"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:text="LOGOUT"
                android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textSize="9dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="monospace" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/settings"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try `android:scaleType="centerInside"`

Comment: Yeah, that is one of the many scaleTypes I tried with no luck. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I haven't seen your comment , probably we have just wrote in the same time. I have deleted the answer. Nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Image display is decided by two factors:

The size of your ImageView (You can think of this as a Frame or Canvas which the image can be drawn onto) and it's position. If the `ImageView` is small then the image can only ever fill that amount of space.

The second factor is the `scaleType` which is described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html). If you tell the `ImageView` via it's `scaleType` attribute to use "center" it will draw from the center at the Images native size. If you use the `scaleType` "fit_center" the Image will scale itself to fit inside the `ImageView` with the correct proportions (it won't be stretched or squashed).

Hope that helps!